# How to amend *only* a git commit message in PyCharm 4.5.3?

Tags: python, git, pycharm, git-commit

In `git` there is a command `git commit --amend` to edit one's last commit message (among other things). I was looking for this type of functionality in PyCharm and can't seem to find it.

When file changes are being added to an amended commit, the *Commit Changes* dialog shows a *Amend commit* checkbox, but I find no obvious way to amend **only** the commit message. (I can trick the checkbox into showing up by selecting a file, checking the *Amend commit* box, and then unselecting the file, but the *Commit* button is greyed out.)

Google turns up "[How to edit a commit message in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999131/how-to-edit-a-commit-message-in-pycharm)" but it was not answered satisfactorily (or perhaps it's not applicable to the current version?). The [help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/committing-changes-to-a-local-git-repository.html) linked to in the previous question does not provide the answer, nor have I been able to find it in the rest of the docs. (Per [meta.stack*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/) [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/) I attempted to update the existing, unanswered question, but my edits were [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9059365).)

Further review turns up "[Using IntelliJ to amend git commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075919/)", a couple years old and without an accepted answer, and since PyCharm is based on IDEA, possibly applicable.

Is this even possible in PyCharm 4.5.3?

Comment: check also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Comment: Why not just do it in the terminal?

Comment: Thanks; I do know how to do `git commit --amend` and I know there are other tools I could use; I'm trying to learn how to use the git features of PyCharm. (Possibly I should not have the _git*_ tags on the question.)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14089715/147024) is applicable to PyCharm and still valid.

Comment: @yole Technically, it probably is a duplicate, but not obviously so -- you'd have to know that IDEA and PyCharm are based on the same code and plugins and assume that nothing has changed in 2 1/2 years. The JetBrains tickets that support referred me to are rather more conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a support request with JetBrains (not expecting much since I'm using the free community version) and was directed to the following enhancement request tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81428
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57979

So, on the authority of JetBrains's support, this is not possible currently; future inquisitors may refer to the above tickets for status.